# fb-like with show-face =true style is weird

Tags: css, facebook

my html for the like button. I use foundation Zurb framewrok if you wonder what's the '`small-12 medium-12 large-12`' is about.

```
<div class="fb-like class='small-12 medium-12 large-12 text-center" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/TheSite/?fref=ts" data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="false"></div>
```

The output is:

[image]

The picture shown is my fb profile image. Obviously I want to get rid of the unwanted white space. But I thought since I set show-face attribute to true,other's fb images also will be shown to fill up the white space, no?

Answer (score 0):

I found that, its better to use like-box instead of like-button

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin